# Deploying react app on github pages front and backend in the same repository

Tags: reactjs, github, deployment

I am trying to deploy a react app with the backend into the same repository on github pages. It all works fine until I add the backend code to it. I can deploy the front-end, but I cannot figure out how to deploy the backend to github.
In my package.json I have the followings:

```
....
    "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "client": "npm run start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
  }
...
```

I have pushed it to github. Installed gh-pages package.
I have added

```
"homepage" : "https://[your-user-name].github.io/[your-repo-name]/"
“predeploy”:
“deploy”:
```

I think this is where I am going wrong. I know what predeploy and deploy should specify, but I have tried to enter a thousand different versions and I am getting error.

Comment: Are you sure Github pages supports custom backends? I might be wrong, but I think it's just a static site hosting service where you can host front end assets.

Comment: That's correct @Tholle

Comment: Ohhhhh...okay. I should have done a bit more research before I have wasted 4 hours of my life. :D

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Github pages will not execute any serverside code. You may only upload static files (html,css,js, images, etc.).

In order to have a  hosted backend you should look for another service like Google Cloud, AWS Lambda, Heroku, etc.

Answer (score 0):

[Vercel](https://vercel.com) is a platform where you can host your frontend and backend both for free. There may be some limits but most of the features are free.