# Issue when deploying with Heroku (Error 504)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, github-pages

I'm deploying a very small React App + Node server to test deployment with Heroku,

I can get the client but not the server,

Repo : https://github.com/Versifiction/ofilms-test-heroku

Website : https://test-ofilms-heroku.herokuapp.com/

In the console, there's a 504 error

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 504 (Gateway Timeout)
xhr.js:166 GET https://test-ofilms-heroku.herokuapp.com/api/message 504 (Gateway Timeout)
```

Do you know what I have to add to correct this 504 error ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deploying react app on github pages front and backend in the same repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52969697/deploying-react-app-on-github-pages-front-and-backend-in-the-same-repository)

Comment: oh ok so I can't deploy backend with Github Pages, right. But I still have the same error with Heroku

Comment: No, you can't deploy backend on GitHub pages.

Comment: Just looking at your repo, where are you running the server?

Comment: in package.json there's a script "server" : "node server.js" which runs the server in server.js file at the root

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got some time to take a look at your repo. It's not the `setupProxy.js`, but instead it's how you've set up your API.

**First issue**: You're trying to serve production assets in development.

```
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "build")));

  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "build", "index.html"));
  });
```

**Fix**: When you're in production, it'll capture requests and fallback to the client `index.html` if a requested route doesn't match.

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV == "production") {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "build")));

  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "build", "index.html"));
  });
}
```

**Second issue**: You're serving the above assets as a wildcard `/` (changed to `*`) before you're serving your API routes. In other words, it'll never reach your `GET` requested API routes since `/` (`*`) catches all `GET` requests first.

**Fix**: All of your API routes must sit above your client production build -- this way, requests flow through the API first and then fallback to the client second.

```
app.get("/api/message", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: "Test déploiement d'O'Films sur Heroku" });
});

app.get("/api/hello", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: "Hello world !" });
});

if (process.env.NODE_ENV == "production") {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "build")));

  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "build", "index.html"));
  });
}

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is on up ${port} now !`);
});
```

---

**Working example repo**: https://github.com/mattcarlotta/ofilms-refactored

Comment: man I want to thank you so much for the time you spent to make this response, everything's working now

Comment: You bet! Glad I could help out.